# Ask user for partial PIN

Tags: php, security

I'm developing an additional security module for a web application, which asks the user to enter a PIN code randomly generated at user signup. The PIN is stored AES-128 encrypted in a db and sent by sms to the new user.

The user will be ask to provide his PIN when certain situations occur (i.e. "strange" accesses, or unusual operations) - and i'd like the user not to enter the entire PIN code, but just 2 digit (for example: the 1st and the 6th).

```
2 4 6 2 9 1 8 3    -> entire PIN
^---------^----    -> digits i'm asking
```

My question is: is the a more secure way to choose which digits to ask? Should i choose them randomly (but an eventual attacker who owns part of the pin could retry until the digits he owns are requested) or should i ask each user always for the same digits - maybe storing their indexes encrypted with the PIN, or generate them with a function parametrized with the PIN itself?

Thanks.

Comment: Just curious, how do you verify these two digits given that the full PIN is hashed?

Comment: You would have to hash each individual digit with it's location within the PIN being clear I guess! Very open to being brute forced.

Comment: The PIN is not hashed, but encrypted.

Comment: In this scenario I would agree encryption trumps being hashed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I find most online banking software implements this is that once it's asked for two digits it will **keep asking for the same** until the user either blocks the account (from too many wrong attempts) or answers it correctly.  After this another 2 digits is randomly selected for next time.

As far as I know this is the only way to mitigate an attacker simply reloading until they get a combination they desire.

Comment: Oh, good, I missed the bit about reloading. +1. What about clearing cookies, though, does that persist the choice of digits?

Comment: @Kerrek - You can't use cookies to decide on the digits as that's simply not secure.  You'd just store two numbers in the DB which relate to the digits requested (server side) - which will change only when the correct digits are supplied

Comment: I see, you want to do this independent of any user session. That's a good idea.

Comment: @m.edmonson: +1. Changing the pair after a succesful login sounds good to me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have secondary, [more secure](http://www.schneier.com/essay-081.html) [way](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2992-while-setting-up-an-account-at-the-national) of authentication, then do ask for random digits but lock the account after a few failed attempts. That way, the chance that an attacker has the correct digits is very small, yet the implications of the same two digits leaking are also mitigated.

[*Edit:* As @m.edmondson suggests, only change the pair after a *successful* login, not before.]

If you just ask for the same two digits over and over, you might as well just have a two-digit PIN.

If a user inadvertently locks herself out, you can always fall back on the secondary authentication to recover the account.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, asking for the same 2 digits everytime is not the same as having 2-digits PIN. Asking for partial PIN is a protection against eavesdropping attacks - it prevents the complete code to be inserted (and, eventually, stolen in its entirety).

Comment: @geezmo: If every aspect of your system only every requires the same two digits, *then* it's no different from a 2-digit PIN, I suppose. If you require different sets of digits at different places, then that's a different story.

Comment: every user would have a different set of digits to enter, in my idea

Comment: @geezmo: I understand, but for each user, only two of the digits would constitute her entire set of credentials, if I understand right. So this only adds a very thin layer of security, only for the specific threat model that *part* of the full set of credentials (which the user now has no reason to use at all) leaks.

Comment: you are right, change pair on a per-user basis adds nothing to system strength. Thanks!